# My UIWebView and labels only work when i scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uitableview

Hi i m trying to asynchronously load labels and UIWebView in subclassed UITableViewCell. It only works after i scroll UITableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"classCustomCell";
    static NSString *cellIdentifierMain=@"classMainTblCell";
    nesneMainTblCell= (classMainTblCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierMain];
    nesneCustomCell = (classCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    if (nesneCustomCell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"classCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        nesneCustomCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if (nesneMainTblCell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"classMainTblCell" owner:self options:nil];
        nesneMainTblCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *dicLoadLabels = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:tableView, @"keyTableView", indexPath, @"keyIndexPath",nesneCustomCell,@"keyCell", nil];


    [self loadLabelsOnCells:dicLoadLabels];

    if (tableView.tag==0) {
        return nesneMainTblCell;
    }
    else{
        return nesneCustomCell;
    }
    return false;
}



-(void)loadLabelsOnCells:(NSDictionary *)dicInfo
{


    UITableView *tableView;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;

    tableView = [dicInfo objectForKey:@"keyTableView"];
    indexPath = [dicInfo objectForKey:@"keyIndexPath"];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString *strName;
        NSString *strScreenName;
        NSString *strText;
        NSString *strStatus;
        NSString *strSentiment;
        UIImage *imgChannel;
        UIWebView *webPic;
        if (tableView.tag==1)

        {
            strName=[[masivAllFbRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:7];
            strScreenName=[[masivAllFbRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:6];
            strText=[[masivAllFbRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:9];
            strStatus=[[masivAllFbRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:8];
            strSentiment=[[masivAllFbRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:5];

            imgChannel=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Facebook-icon.png"];
            webPic=[nesneShowPicInWebView setPicToWebView:nesneCustomCell.webUserPic adressURL:[[masivAllFbRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:12]];
        }
        if (tableView.tag==2)
        {


            strName=[[masivAllTwRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:7];
            strScreenName=[[masivAllTwRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:6];
            strText=[[masivAllTwRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:9];
            strStatus=[[masivAllTwRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:8];
            strSentiment=[[masivAllTwRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:5];

            imgChannel=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Twitter-icon.png"];
            webPic=[nesneShowPicInWebView setPicToWebView:nesneCustomCell.webUserPic adressURL:[[masivAllTwRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:12]];

        }

        if (tableView.tag==3)
        {


            strName=[[masivAllFilitredRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:7];
            strScreenName=[[masivAllFilitredRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:6];
            strText=[[masivAllFilitredRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:9];
            strStatus=[[masivAllFilitredRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:8];
            strSentiment=[[masivAllFilitredRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:5];


            webPic=[nesneShowPicInWebView setPicToWebView:nesneCustomCell.webUserPic adressURL:[[masivAllFilitredRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:12]];

            [nesneCustomCell.btnCheck addTarget:self
                                         action:@selector(actionButtonOnCellAll:)
                               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


            nesneCustomCell.btnCheck=[nesneTableCellsJobs checkMarksInRefresh:masivCheckedAllCells indexPath:indexPath Cell:nesneCustomCell button:nesneCustomCell.btnCheck];

            nesneCustomCell.btnCheck.tag=indexPath.row;
            if([[masivAllChannelName objectAtIndex:nesneCustomCell.tag] isEqual:@"Twitter"])
            {
                imgChannel=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Twitter-icon.png"];


            }
            else
            {
                imgChannel=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Facebook-icon.png"];
            }

        }


        dispatch_queue_t mainThreadQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
        dispatch_async(mainThreadQueue, ^{
            //  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (tableView.tag==1) {

                nesneCustomCell.lblName.text=strName;
                nesneCustomCell.lblScreenName.text=strScreenName;
                nesneCustomCell.lblText.text=strText;
                nesneCustomCell.lblStatus.text=strStatus;
                nesneCustomCell.lblSentimental.text=strSentiment;
                [nesneCustomCell.imgChannel setImage:imgChannel];

                nesneCustomCell.webUserPic=[nesneShowPicInWebView setPicToWebView:nesneCustomCell.webUserPic adressURL:[[masivAllFbRecentPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:12]];

                NSLog(@"webViewPic**=%@",nesneCustomCell.webUserPic);
                [nesneCustomCell.btnCheck addTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(actionButtonOnCellFb:)
                                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


                nesneCustomCell.btnCheck=[nesneTableCellsJobs checkMarksInRefresh:masivCheckedFbCells indexPath:indexPath Cell:nesneCustomCell button:nesneCustomCell.btnCheck];

                nesneCustomCell.btnCheck.tag=indexPath.row;


            }
            if (tableView.tag==2) {


                UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                nesneCustomCell=currentCell;
                [nesneCustomCell setNeedsLayout];
                NSLog(@"loading **");
                nesneCustomCell.lblName.text=strName;
                nesneCustomCell.lblScreenName.text=strScreenName;
                nesneCustomCell.lblText.text=strText;
                nesneCustomCell.lblStatus.text=strStatus;
                nesneCustomCell.lblSentimental.text=strSentiment;
                [nesneCustomCell.imgChannel setImage:imgChannel];
                nesneCustomCell.webUserPic=webPic;

                [nesneCustomCell.btnCheck addTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(actionButtonOnCellTw:)
                                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


                nesneCustomCell.btnCheck=[nesneTableCellsJobs checkMarksInRefresh:masivCheckedTwCells indexPath:indexPath Cell:nesneCustomCell button:nesneCustomCell.btnCheck];

                nesneCustomCell.btnCheck.tag=indexPath.row;

            }

            if (tableView.tag==3)
            {


                UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                nesneCustomCell=currentCell;
                [nesneCustomCell setNeedsLayout];
                NSLog(@"loading **");
                nesneCustomCell.lblName.text=strName;
                nesneCustomCell.lblScreenName.text=strScreenName;
                nesneCustomCell.lblText.text=strText;
                nesneCustomCell.lblStatus.text=strStatus;
                nesneCustomCell.lblSentimental.text=strSentiment;
                [nesneCustomCell.imgChannel setImage:imgChannel];
                nesneCustomCell.webUserPic=webPic;

                [nesneCustomCell.btnCheck addTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(actionButtonOnCellAll:)
                                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


                nesneCustomCell.btnCheck=[nesneTableCellsJobs checkMarksInRefresh:masivCheckedAllCells indexPath:indexPath Cell:nesneCustomCell button:nesneCustomCell.btnCheck];

                nesneCustomCell.btnCheck.tag=indexPath.row;
            }

        });
    });
}
```

SubClassed UITableViewCell H.

```
@interface classCustomCell : UITableViewCell
{

}
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblScreenName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblText;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblStatus;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblSentimental;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *btnCheck;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgChannel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webUserPic;
```

//classShowPicInWebView.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface classShowPicInWebView :          NSObject<UIWebViewDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender,NSURLC  onnectionDataDelegate>

{

    bool isDone;
    NSURLConnection *con;
    NSURLRequest *req;
    UIWebView *webProfilePic;
}

@property(retain,nonatomic) UIWebView *webProfilePic;

-(UIWebView *)setPicToWebView:(UIWebView *)webView adressURL:(NSString *)strUrlAdress;

@end
```

//classShowPicInWebView.m
    #import "classShowPicInWebView.h"

```
@implementation classShowPicInWebView
@synthesize webProfilePic;

-(UIWebView *)setPicToWebView:(UIWebView *)webView  adressURL:(NSString *)strUrlAdress
{
    webProfilePic=webView;
    webProfilePic.delegate=self;
    if([strUrlAdress length]==0)
    {
        strUrlAdress=@"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png";
    }
    NSLog(@"profiles2=%@",strUrlAdress);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrlAdress];
    req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webProfilePic loadRequest:req];

    return webProfilePic;
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

{
    if (!isDone) {
        isDone = NO;

        con=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

        [con start];
        return NO;

    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"error -%@",[error description]);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:  (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount]==0) {
        isDone=YES;
        NSURLCredential *credential=[NSURLCredential  credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    }

    else
    {

        [[challenge sender]cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    isDone=YES;
    [webProfilePic loadRequest:req];
    [con cancel];
}

-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:    (NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{

    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod    isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];

}
```

If i wont do it in async then it is working but i need to do it async. There is no mistake about allocations or in setPicToWebView method. Because it works in sync mode. I can't get it why it is only working after i scroll it in asnyc.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `nesneCustomCell`? Perhaps show the rest of your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Also what is `nesneShowPicInWebView`?

Comment: @Popeye this is object of class which fill UIWebView with website. nesneCustomCell is object of subclassed UITableViewCell. There is no mistake with this method. I use it in many places.

Comment: Just so you know we don't know what these are so please include all relevant code whether you think it is fine or not.

Comment: @Popeye I know you are right, i just did not post because it is a lot but i will post all now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it asynchronously, then you need to get the details to come in any other method say viewDidLoad and then reload tableview once you get the result.

The problem is the tableView returns cell before your tasks is completed and result is the block inside your asynchronous method is executed after your cell has been returned, it should be done before.

Comment: I reload TableView after got result and it works, i can see pics and labels are filled. But i don't think this is a good way. Thanks for help.